# useNavigate() not redirecting to '/protected'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

The API is working fine, it returns the token that then is saved in my local memory but it doesn't redirect for some reason. If I refresh my window it takes me straight to the `"/protected"` page.

LoginForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';
import api from './api';

function LoginForm() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const response = await api.post('/authenticate', { email, password });
    return response.data;
  };

  const { mutate, isLoading } = useMutation(handleLogin, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
      console.log(data.token);
      navigate('/protected');
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      setError(error.response.data);
    },
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    mutate();
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Email:
        <input
          type="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Password:
        <input
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      {error && <div>{error}</div>}
      <button type="submit" disabled={isLoading}>
        {isLoading ? 'Logging in...' : 'Login'}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Here is my `App.js` as the protected page does not matter as it only has an `<h1></h1>`. My API does not apply either as I get the required token without an issue. The only issue is redirecting. I did force window reload but that is a work-around that I bet is not safe?

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
import ProtectedResource from './ProtectedResource';
import api from './api';

function App() {
  const { isLoading, error, data: isLoggedIn } = useQuery('isLoggedIn', async () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      try {
        await api.get('/resource', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        });
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          localStorage.removeItem('token');
        }
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>An error occurred: {error.message}</p>;

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={isLoggedIn ? <Navigate to="/protected" /> : <LoginForm />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/protected"
          element={isLoggedIn ? <ProtectedResource /> : <Navigate to="/" />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

The code is using `localStorage` as the source of truth, but updating localStorage doesn't trigger the `App` React component to rerender with the new authentication value in order to correctly protect routes or redirect when necessary. The token value is stored in localStorage and the navigation action to `"/protected"` is effected, but because `App` didn't rerender, the `useQuery` hook didn't rerun to check the user's token value.

Refactor the code to add state to `App` that is updated upon successful log in & out. This will trigger `App` to rerender and rerun `useQuery` and check the stored `token` value.

Example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = React.useState(); // <-- state

  const { isLoading, error, data: isLoggedIn } = useQuery("isLoggedIn", async () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      try {
        await api.get("/resource", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
          }
        });
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
        }
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (isLoading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>An error occurred: {error.message}</p>;

  return (
    ...
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            isLoggedIn ? (
              <Navigate to="/protected" />
            ) : (
              <LoginForm setToken={setToken} /> // <-- pass setter
            )
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/protected"
          element={isLoggedIn ? <ProtectedResource /> : <Navigate to="/" />}
        />
      </Routes>
    ...
  );
}
```

```
function LoginForm({ setToken }) { // <-- consume setToken callback
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const response = await api.post("/authenticate", { email, password });
    return response.data;
  };

  const { mutate, isLoading } = useMutation(handleLogin, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
      setToken(data.token); // <-- update token state
      navigate("/protected");
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      setError(error.response.data);
    }
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    mutate();
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      ...
    </form>
  );
}
```

### Demo

[image: Edit usenavigate-not-redirecting-to-protected]